# Why multithreading in c++ DLL get error C3867 when building?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, executable, stdthread

I am using VS2019

Trying to call a thread in DLL. to run two executables simultaneously with **detach**

following threads worked when I Run a normal c++ program

I get error

**Error C3867   'myClass::runexeone': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    myGateway C:\Users\user\Downloads\Demo\myGateway\myplugin.cpp   21**

**plugin header**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread> 


#define MYPLUGIN_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C"
{
    MYPLUGIN_EXPORT void WINAPI OnStart();
}
```

**pluging.cpp**

```
#include "plugin.h"
using namespace std;

class myClass
{
public:
    myClass()
    {

    }
    ~myClass()
    {

    }
    void onStart()
    {
        std::thread(runexeone).detach();
        std::thread(runexetwo).detach();
    }

    void runexeone()
    {
        int exerunpne = system("cmd /C \"%MY_ROOT%\\bin\\Mytest.exe\" -ORBEndpoint iiop://localhost:12345 -d");
    }


    void runexetwo()
    {
        int exeruntwo = system("cmd /C \"%MY_ROOT%\\bin\\Mytest_2.exe\" -ORBEndpoint iiop://localhost:12345 -d");
    }

};

myClass& getmyclass()
{
    static myClass myclass;
    return myclass;
}


MYPLUGIN_EXPORT void WINAPI OnStart()
{
    getmyClass().onStart();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MSalters already mentioned, you provided the wrong data type for the functor for std::thread.  If you cannot make the method static (which you can actually at least for the current state of your code, but to let this not be unstated here), you can do this

```
  void onStart()
  {
    std::thread(std::bind(&myClass::runexeone, this)).detach();
  }
```

But be careful about the lifetime/existence of your object/this!

Comment: TBH I'd use `[this]() { runexeone(); }`. I find that lambda's give better error messages. But strictly speaking that's not even necessary, `std::thread::thread` will do the bind for you. I.e. `std::thread(&myClass::runexeone, this).detach();`

Comment: Yes but at least for former compilers, it was sometimes annyoing for the parameter forwarding case with lambda usage. std::placeholder for std::bind was a nice boilerplate reducer here :) Thanks for the syntactic sugar about std::thread's own ability for this!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `runexeone` is an unqualified name of a member function, and `std::thread` needs something executable. `runexeone` isn't. VC++ tries to guess from context what you mean, but the suggestion isn't enough. Even if you had written `&myClass::runexeone`, it still wouldn't have worked, because `myClass::runexeone` also needs a `this` pointer. You can fix the latter problem by making it `static`.

Compiler suggestions work best when there's just one problem.